# My code is producing indexError

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, syntax-error

My code provides the following error, would anybody be able to assist me in what is going wrong

if (RecentScores[count].Score) < (RecentScores[count + 1].Score):
IndexError: list index out of range

```
def rankScores(RecentScores):
  noMoreSwaps = False
  while not noMoreSwaps:
    noMoreSwaps = True
    for count in range (1,len(RecentScores)):                                  
      if (RecentScores[count].Score) < (RecentScores[count + 1].Score):
        noMoreSwaps = False
        tempScore = RecentScores[count].Score
        tempName = RecentScores[count].Name
        RecentScores[count].Score = RecentScores[count+1].Score      
        RecentScores[count].Name = RecentScores[count+1].Name
        RecentScores[count+1].Score = tempScore
        RecentScores[count+1].Name = tempName
  DisplayRecentScores(RecentScores)
```

Would be extremely thankful if anyone could help

Comment: I would recommend you read and follow [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index in most programming languages *starts with 0*. In the line

```
for count in range (1,len(RecentScores)):
```

you are looping from `1` to `length - 1` (I'm calling `length` to `len(RecentScores)`). But in the line

```
if (RecentScores[count].Score) < (RecentScores[count + 1].Score):
```

you are accessing to the `list/tuple` with the index

```
count + 1
```

Let's say the loop is in the *last* iteration. The value of `count` will be `length - 1`. Then, in the `if` condition, you try to access to the `list/tuple` with

```
RecentScores[length - 1 + 1]
```

which is equivalent to

```
RecentScores[length]
```

This will raise the exception because you are accessing to an index higher than the allowed.

**How can you solve it?**

In order to avoid using that not-allowed index, you can change your loop range to a smaller one:

```
for count in range (1, len(RecentScores) - 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for count in range (1,len(RecentScores)):                                  
  if (RecentScores[count].Score) < (RecentScores[count + 1].Score):
```

The biggest value `count` takes in this loop is the length of RecentScores.
Then in the last iteration of the loop you try to access one past the end with:
`RecentScores[count + 1]`

Trying to access this gives you the `IndexError: list index out of range` that you see.

Loop index starts at 0 so to fix this you need to change the range your loop operates on:

```
    for count in range (0,len(RecentScores)-1):
```

If what you want to do is sort the entire list of scores as suggested by your comment (note that this isn't what the code in the question does but) then it would be better to do it like this:

```
sortedScores = sorted(RecentScores, key=lambda x: x.Score, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! So how do I solve that?providing I want the program to sort all the scores in order

Answer (score 0):

`for count in range(0,len(RecentScores)-1):` always remember that indices start at 0 and go to length-1. And since you are accessing something at index+1 you additionally have to substract 1, since range(a,b) goes from a to b-1